# Ember component: A property of X was modified inside the didInsertElement hook deprecation, where should the set go?

Tags: ember.js

The full deprecation message is `DEPRECATION: A property of <orders-app@view:test-holder::ember3010> was modified inside the didInsertElement hook. You should never change properties on components, services or models during didInsertElement because it causes significant performance degradation.`

To simplify the scenario lets say we have a component with an input box and we want to set the textbox date to today plus a number of days `numberOfDays`. So if today is January 3rd 2015 and `numberOfDays=2` then the textbox value should be 05-01-2015 (assuming we want DD-MM-YYYY formatting). So our setup could be:

date-shower.hbs

```
{{input type="text" value=dateInput}}
```

components/date-shower.js

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var numberOfDays = this.get('numberOfDays');
    var dayToUse = new Date(); // today
    dayToUse.setDate(dayToUse.getDate() + numberOfDays);

    this.set('dateInput', moment(nextDay).format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
  }
});
```

We then might use this with something like

```
{{date-shower numberOfDays=2}}
```

When it makes sense for a component to calculate the default for one it's properties itself, based off a property passed to it, what hook should I use instead of didInsertElement to prevent the deprecation message?

Comment: You could make `dateInput` into a cp that depends on `numberOfDays`

Comment: I'm slightly concerned by dateInput being a computed and also being the value of the input box, if the user edits the input field they are editing dateInput value, but its a computed, is this ok?

Comment: The other example that comes to mind would be a checkbox - in the first half of the month we want it to default to checked, the other half of the month unchecked. Say we had `{{input type="checkbox" value=dateChecked}}`, if the user checks the box and I later want to know it's state in a another action how will I know via a `this.get`? The computed may continue to return based on the calculation but the user has overridden it?

Comment: The plot thickens :O, let me update my answer ^^, can you add the template part where dateInput is being used, and what dateInput's value and default values will be

Comment: I'm tempted to get a convo going on ember discuss, I can't see a way in ember 1.13 for this scenario without getting the deprecation warning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84816/discussion-between-kitler-and-knightsy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use a computed property to handle setting and getting `dateInput`, something along the line of :

```
dateInputHandler: computed('numberOfDays', {
  set(key, val) {
    if (val) {
      this.set('dateInput', val);
    } else {
      this.set('dateInput', null);
    }
    return val;
  },
  get() {
    let dateInput = this.get('dateInput');
    if (!dateInput) {
      let numberOfDays = this.get('numberOfDays');
      let dayToUse = new Date(); // today
      dateInput = dayToUse.setDate(dayToUse.getDate() + numberOfDays);
      this.set('dateInput', dateInput);
    }
    return dateInput;
  }
})
```

And in your template you would use `value=dateInputHandler`

Comment: This is nearly there - i get build errors with it in it's current form. If you could update it to do the equivalent of the first 3 lines of my original didInsertElement to give a default value then we will be on our way :)

Comment: Updated to add your defaults, let me know what the build errors are

Comment: The build error was my fault. I love the get/set syntax. I've set up a jsbin with your answer so far http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tadubi/edit?html,css,js,console,output - the problem is the input box doesn't get populated because at initialization the computed doesn't get called at least once, the test button also shows a second issue that the component containing this one doesn't get set (because the computed isn't set at least once)

Comment: In addition to the above I added a dateChanged action and passed that to the component and sent that when setting dateInput to bubble up the change in data in a Ember 2.0 type way.

Answer (score 5):

I would make `dateInput` a computed property on the component and let Ember handle setting the property for you to ensure it happens at the right time:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const { Component, computed } = Ember;

export default Component.extend({
  didInsertElement() {
    // nothing needed in here
  },

  dateInput: computed('numberOfDays', function() {
    let numberOfDays = this.get('numberOfDays');
    let dayToUse = new Date(); // today

    dayToUse.setDate(dayToUse.getDate() + numberOfDays);

    return moment(nextDay).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
  })
});
```

This way, your `dateInput` value will get computed as soon as `numberOfDays` becomes available.

Comment: Nice! Question - dateInput is also linked to the value of the input box, so say the user changes it - is dateInput as a computed going to play nicely with this?